# Strange error on Android Studio after changing phone targets or building bundle

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I can be using Android Studio (4.1.1) fine with one phone as the target to run the code on for hours, then as soon as I switch to a different phone I'll get errors like this:

> Entry name 'file path' collided

I then do a clean and it all works fine again.

This will also happen after using the build signed bundle menu. Clean will fix it as well.

Anyone have any idea why this might happen?

Answer (score 0):

Please delete app>build and build folders in the project path on your computer...

This issue is resolved by deleting APKs generated by previous build which existing in release and debug folders.

Invalidating cache and rebuild would not help if you have not deleted previously generated APKs

**Just delete the apk generated by the previous compilation.**

Comment: I went into each module including the app module and also into the top level folder and deleted every build folder I found and the issue is still happening. Did I miss something?